# Python: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matrices, bucle-for

Estoy teniendo constantemente este error y no se como solucionarlo.

Este es el código:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import random

g_row=10
g_col=10

m_prob = np.ones((g_row, g_col), dtype=np.int)

s_acomulada = list(itertools.accumulate(itertools.chain.from_iterable(m_prob)))

papeletas = np.ones((g_row, g_col), dtype=np.int)

for i, fila in enumerate(s_acomulada):
  for j, n in enumerate(fila):
    papeletas[i][j] = tuple(range(inicio, inicio+n))
    inicio += n

print(papeletas)
```

Y al ejecutarlo me devuelve esto:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

Me gustaría también que m_prob, s_acomulada y papeletas sean las tres matrices de 10x10, como m_prob, si es posible.

Un saludo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce en el segundo `for` anidado porque `fila` es un entero. Esto ocurre porque  `s_acumulada` es una lista unidimensional de enteros ya que para calcular la suma acumulada se aplana `m_prob` previamente.

Ten en cuenta que NumPy tiene su propia función para realizar la suma acumulada, [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html). Cuando trabajes con arrays de NumPy usa los métodos que este proporciona siempre que puedas para preservar la eficiencia. Para conservar las dimensiones simplemente aplica el método  `reshape` después de llevar a cabo la suma acumulada.

Por otro lado, si a `papeletas` le vas a asignar tuplas de python no puedes inicializarlo con tipo entero, los arrays de NumPy ,a diferencia de una lista python, no pueden cambiar de tipo ni mezclar tipos alegremente. Debes inicializarlo con `dtype` `object`.

Por último, te falta declarar `inicio` antes del `for`.

```
import numpy as np

g_row=200
g_col=200

m_prob = np.ones((g_row, g_col), dtype=np.int)
papeletas = np.empty((g_row, g_col), dtype=object)
s_acumulada = np.cumsum(m_prob, axis=None, dtype=np.int).reshape(m_prob.shape)

inicio=1
for i, fila in enumerate(s_acumulada):
  for j, n in enumerate(fila):
    papeletas[i][j] = tuple(range(inicio, inicio+n))
    inicio += n
```

> ```
> >>> m_prob
> array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
>        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>
> >>> m_prob.shape
> (10, 10)
>
> >>> s_acumulada
> array([[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10],
>        [ 11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20],
>        [ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30],
>        [ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40],
>        [ 41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50],
>        [ 51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60],
>        [ 61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70],
>        [ 71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80],
>        [ 81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90],
>        [ 91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100]], dtype=int32)
>
> >>> s_acumulada.shape
> (10, 10)
>
> >>> papeletas
> array([[(1,), (2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9, 10), (11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
>         (16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), (22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28),
>         (29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36),
>         (37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45),
>         (46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55)],
>        [(56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66),
>         ...]...], dtype=object)
>
> >>> papeletas.shape
> (10, 10)
> ```